# Down arrow symbol

Tags: html, css, properties, tags

I want to add a symbol like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF5PU.png) on the button on my website, I've been looking for a symbol like this, but could not find it. what to add to my html and css scripts ?

Comment: Usually that arrow is a SVG background. If you need to use a unicode symbol you could use a `>` inside a span element and use a CSS rotation along the Z axis

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_arrows.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Fontawesome which provides a lot of icons even in the free version.

For down angle: https://fontawesome.com/icons/angle-down?style=solid